# How can I check downloaded files with Selenoid?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenoid

I'm running some java selenium tests on hosted Selenoid hub and I have to download some files during these tests.

How can I check these files during the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated API for that: https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_accessing_files_downloaded_with_browser